# Project.json conditional referencing dependencies

Tags: c#, dependencies, package, dnx

I am building a program which uses different dependencies for each platform.

Is there any way to get dependencies on a condition like

```
  if(WINDOWS)
  "dependencies": {
    "mypackageWindows": "1.0.0"
  }

  if(LINUX)
  "dependencies": {
    "mypackageLinux": "1.0.0"
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean referencing different libraries for different target platforms (runtimes in terms of project.json)?

Comment: Did you solve it?